# Exercise 2.2.13 (Velleman's How to prove it)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

Show that the statements $A \subseteq B $  and $A \cup B = B $ are equivalent by writing each in logical symbols and then showing that the resulting formulas are equivalent.

Statement one is equivalent to $ \forall x (x\in a \rightarrow x\in b) $

Statement two is equivalent to $ \forall x((x\in a \lor x\in b)\iff(x\in b))    $

I'm struggling reaching from one statement to the other. Perhaphs there is an alternate way to write either of the statements and reach the other?

Comment: The two statements are correct.

Comment: 1) if $x \in A \cup B$, then either $x \in A$ or $x \in B$. In the first case, also $x \in B$. Thus, in both cases $x \in B$. If $x \in B$, then $x \in A \cup B$. Thus $A \cup B = B$.

Comment: 2) similar.....

Comment: Sorry I fail to see it. I normally just write out the statements into simpler form till reaching the other. May you please elaborate a bit more on your method. @MauroALLEGRANZA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you look at the hint given for this problem in the book?  The hint is to look at exercise 11 from Section 1.5.  Part (a) of that exercise asks you to show that $(P \vee Q) \leftrightarrow Q$ is equivalent to $P \to Q$.

Comment: I actually but opened section 1.4 rather than 1.5  this makes sense now. Thanks.